# ORDS no conecta con la base de datos

Tags: base-de-datos, rest, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-12c

Mi problema es que, cuando intento acceder a ords desde el navegador mediante la URI http://localhost:8080/ords/ , este responde con:

```
URLMappingNotFoundException [statusCode=404, reasons=[The request could not be assigned to any database. Check if the request URL is correct and if the URLs to the database mappings have been configured correctly]…
```

Desde el departamento de Operaciones me han instalado ORDS 19.4 en modo standalone, sin APEX, en una máquina para desarrollo. Me han enviado su fichero ords_params.properties.

Por mi parte, he ejecutado ORDS desde SQL Developer.

He abierto la vista de Administración de ORDS con el usuario ords_admin, y he introducido la contraseña de ORDS_PUBLIC_USER tal y como se especifica en el fichero de parámetros.

Si valido mediante Configuración de Prueba, me indica que la configuración se ha realizado satisfactoriamente.

Selecciono Configuración de Carga para que los cambios suban a ORDS, y se reflejen en defaults.xml.

No he especificado ninguna conexión en Database Values, por lo que no tiene pool de conexión.

El esquema está habilitado para REST. La conexión a base de datos es vía TNS

Aporto el log de la ejecución, y los ficheros  tnsnames.ora, ords_params.properties, defaults.xml, standalone.properties y url-mapping.xml.

Archivo: tnsnames.ora

```
...
DECORP5 = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL=TCP) (HOST=exahost.gobe.pri) (PORT=1521) ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA= (SERVICE_NAME=decorp5) ) 
  )
```

Archivo: ORDS Log:

```
D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\SQLDEVELOPER\jdk\jre\bin\java -Duser.language=es -Duser.country=ES -jar D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\ords\ords.war configdir D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\ords\configuracion
2020-04-21T09:05:48.748Z INFO   Defina config.dir en D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\ords\configuracion en: D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\ords\ords.war
D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\sqldeveloper\sqldeveloper\bin>
D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\SQLDEVELOPER\jdk\jre\bin\java -Duser.language=es -Duser.country=ES -jar D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\ords\ords.war standalone --parameterFile D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\ords\params\sqldev_ords_params.properties
2020-04-21T09:05:55.067Z INFO   Usuario creado: ords_admin en archivo: D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\ords\configuracion\ords\credentials
2020-04-21T09:05:55.100Z INFO   Usuario creado: ords_dev en archivo: D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\ords\configuracion\ords\credentials
2020-04-21 11:05:56.356:INFO::main: Logging initialized @4022ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
2020-04-21 11:05:56.584:INFO:oeju.TypeUtil:main: JVM Runtime does not support Modules
2020-04-21T09:05:56.774Z INFO   HTTP and HTTP/2 cleartext listening on host: localhost port: 8080
2020-04-21T09:05:56.828Z INFO   The document root is serving static resources located in: D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\ords\configuracion\ords\standalone\doc_root
2020-04-21 11:05:57.269:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.4.24.v20191120; built: 2019-11-22T11:09:44.612Z; git: 8b8c80157294e38f81ef8ea2358a0c49bf5db918; jvm 1.8.0_212-b10
2020-04-21 11:05:57.292:INFO:oejs.session:main: DefaultSessionIdManager workerName=node0
2020-04-21 11:05:57.292:INFO:oejs.session:main: No SessionScavenger set, using defaults
2020-04-21 11:05:57.293:INFO:oejs.session:main: node0 Scavenging every 600000ms
2020-04-21T09:05:57.790Z INFO   No pools configured yet
2020-04-21T09:05:57.901Z INFO   Oracle REST Data Services initialized
Oracle REST Data Services version : 19.4.0.r3521226
Oracle REST Data Services server info: jetty/9.4.24.v20191120

2020-04-21 11:05:58.350:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@35a50a4c{/ords,null,AVAILABLE}
2020-04-21 11:05:58.351:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.h.ContextHandler@3439f68d{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2020-04-21 11:05:58.397:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@b9b00e0{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1, h2c]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2020-04-21 11:05:58.398:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @6064ms
2020-04-22T07:29:33.891Z INFO   reloaded pools: []
```

Archivo: ords_params.properties

```
db.connectionType=tns
db.tnsDirectory=/network/admin
db.tnsAliasName=decorp5
rest.services.ords.add=true
schema.tablespace.default=SYSAUX
schema.tablespace.temp=TEMP
user.public.password=ordsdesa1ublic
user.tablespace.default=SYSAUX
user.tablespace.temp=TEMP
bequeath.connect=false
ords.admin.password=oracle
ords.admin.username=ords_admin
ords.sqldev.password=oracle
ords.sqldev.username=ords_dev
restEnabledSql.active = true
plsql.gateway.add=false
rest.services.apex.add=false
standalone.mode=true
standalone.http.port=8080
standalone.use.https=false
migrate.apex.rest=false
```

Archive: standalone.properties

```
jetty.port=8080
standalone.context.path=/ords
standalone.doc.root=D\:\\app\\my_user\\product\\12.2.0\\dbhome_1\\ords\\configuracion\\ords\\standalone\\doc_root
standalone.scheme.do.not.prompt=true
standalone.static.context.path=/i
standalone.static.do.not.prompt=true
```

Archivo: defaults.xml

````
```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
<comment>
   Listener Administration
   Oracle SQL Developer 19.2.1.247.2212
   Last Update: Wed Apr 22 12:13:34 CEST 2020
</comment>
<entry key="db.password">@05D9AD8E979160A32...</entry>
<entry key="db.connectionType">tns</entry>
<entry key="db.hostname"/>
<entry key="db.port">1521</entry>
<entry key="db.tnsAliasName">DECORP5</entry>
<entry key="db.tnsDirectory">D:\app\my_user\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin</entry>
<entry key="jdbc.DriverType">thin</entry>
<entry key="jdbc.InitialLimit">3</entry>
<entry key="jdbc.MinLimit">1</entry>
<entry key="jdbc.MaxLimit">10</entry>
<entry key="jdbc.MaxStatementsLimit">10</entry>
<entry key="jdbc.InactivityTimeout">1800</entry>
<entry key="jdbc.statementTimeout">900</entry>
<entry key="security.inclusionList"/>
<entry key="security.exclusionList"/>
<entry key="security.disableDefaultExclusionList">false</entry>
<entry key="security.validationFunctionType">plsql</entry>
<entry key="security.requestValidationFunction"/>
<entry key="security.maxEntries">2000</entry>
<entry key="security.verifySSL">false</entry>
<entry key="cache.caching">false</entry>
<entry key="cache.procedureNameList"/>
<entry key="cache.type">lru</entry>
<entry key="cache.maxEntries">500</entry>
<entry key="cache.expiration">7</entry>
<entry key="cache.duration">days</entry>
<entry key="cache.directory">/tmp/apex/cache</entry>
<entry key="procedure.preProcess"/>
<entry key="procedure.postProcess"/>
<entry key="misc.defaultPage">apex</entry>
<entry key="apex.docTable">FLOWS_FILES.WWV_FLOW_FILE_OBJECTS$</entry>
<entry key="apex.extensions"/>
<entry key="log.procedure">false</entry>
<entry key="debug.output">console</entry>
<entry key="debug.printDebugToScreen">true</entry>
<entry key="error.keepErrorMessages">true</entry>
<entry key="log.logging">false</entry>
<entry key="status.statistics">true</entry>
<entry key="apex.excel2collection">false</entry>
<entry key="apex.excel2collection.onecollection">true</entry>
<entry key="apex.excel2collection.useSheetName">false</entry>
<entry key="apex.excel2collection.name"/>
<entry key="sqldev.name">Configuración de Administración</entry>
<entry key="sqldev.description">Administración de los servicios REST a desarrollar en la instancia corporativa DECORP5.</entry>
<entry key="sqldev.version">19.2.1.247.2212</entry>
<entry key="restEnabledSql.active">true</entry>
<entry key="jdbc.MaxConnectionReuseCount">1000</entry>
<entry key="cache.monitorInterval">60</entry>
<entry key="misc.compress"/>
</properties>
```
````

Archivo: url-mapping.xml

````
```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <pool-config xmlns="http://xmlns.oracle.com/apex/pool-config"/>
```
````

Muchas gracias por tomarte la molestia